# ListView not displayed after update in Json Data

Tags: json, api, flutter, listview, dart

Status response code is 200 but the ListView is not displayed and stuck on the CircularProgressIndicator.
When I had 2 items in the Json data it was displaying just fine but as I added another item it doesn't show up!
I've tried removing ListView.separated and using ListView.builder instead and also tried using StreamBuilder but I don't seem to be using it correctly as I'm fairly new to Flutter. If I do have to use StreamBuilder can I be guided through how to use it properly here? Thank You.

**Here's my API_manager.dart file:**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:aritic/models/contactsModel.dart';

// ignore: camel_case_types
class API_Manager {
  Future<ContactsModel> getContacts() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var contactsModel;
    String contacts_url =
        'https://exampleapi.com';
    String basicAuth = 'Basic auth key example';
    try {
      var response = await client.get(contacts_url,
          headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonString = response.body;
        var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
        contactsModel = ContactsModel.fromJson(jsonMap);
      }
    } catch (Exception) {
      return contactsModel;
    }
    return contactsModel;
  }
}
```

**My UI Code:**

```
import 'package:aritic/models/contactsModel.dart';
import 'package:aritic/services/api_manager.dart';

class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactsPageState createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Future<ContactsModel> _contactsModel;
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, initialIndex: 0, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabIndex);
    _contactsModel = API_Manager().getContacts();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.removeListener(_handleTabIndex);
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleTabIndex() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Contacts'),
            bottom: PreferredSize(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: TabBar(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    isScrollable: true,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                    indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        child: Text('Contacts'),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Text('Companies'),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0)),
            actions: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                child: FutureBuilder<ContactsModel>(
                    future: _contactsModel,
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<ContactsModel> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ListView.separated(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.contacts.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            List keys = snapshot.data.contacts.keys.toList();
                            List values =
                                snapshot.data.contacts.values.toList();
                            var contact = values[index];
                            return InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ViewContact()));
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: 50,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      contact.owner.firstName +
                                          " " +
                                          contact.owner.lastName,
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      contact.owner.username,
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 5,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                             return SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      } else
                        return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                    Colors.cyan)));
                    })),
            Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                child: ListView(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ViewCompany()));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'example company name',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'example company domain',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ViewCompany()));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'example company name',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'example company domain',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ]),
          floatingActionButton: _bottomButtons(),
        ));
  }

  Widget _bottomButtons() {
    return _tabController.index == 0
        ? FloatingActionButton(
            shape: StadiumBorder(),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                return AddContacts();
              }));
            },
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.person_add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ))
        : FloatingActionButton(
            shape: StadiumBorder(),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                return AddCompany();
              }));
            },
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

**Json sample(complete json too big to upload here):**

```
{
    "total": "187144",
    "contacts": {
        "897": {
            "isPublished": true,
        "id": 897,
            "fields": {
                "core": {
                    "points": {
                        "id": "47",
                        "label": "Points"
                    },
                    "firstname": {
                        "id": "2",
                        "label": "First Name",
                        "value": "Jason"
                    },
                    "lastname": {
                        "id": "3",
                        "label": "Last Name",
                        "value": "Lamuda"
                    },
                    "...": {
                             "..." : "..."
                            }
                },
            "ipAddresses": [
                {
                    "ip": "70.127.91.131",
                    "ipDetails": {
                        "city": "Bradenton",
                        "region": "Florida",
                        "timezone": "America/New_York",
                    }
                },
                 "...": {
                             "..." : "..."
                            }
```

**Output Screen(stuck on CircularProgressIndicator):** [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIV5F.jpg)

Comment: instead of ```future: _contactsModel,``` do it like ```future: API_Manager().getContacts(),```

Comment: Share this `contactsModel = ContactsModel.fromJson(jsonMap);` and the json with newly added elements. If it was working before but then stopped after you added something new, the problem will be with the new thing that has been added.

Comment: @Reign didn't work, I just gave an updated json and created new contactsModel and it showed the 3rd item, but when i added another 4th item still the same issue.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad the json is crossing 30000 characters and I'm not able to upload it here, I just gave an updated json and created new contactsModel and it showed the 3rd item, but when i added another 4th item still the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a function like

```
Future getContacts()async{
      _contactsModel = API_Manager().getContacts();
 }
```

then inside your initState

```
getContacts().then((value){
  setState((){});
 })
```

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError: The method 'then' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: then<Null>(Closure:(dynamic) => Null)`

Comment: Hi, I added `async` to the function and the error is gone but my problem is not solved, still stuck on `CircularProgressIndicator`.

Comment: @ShreyasBhardwaj change `future: _contactsModel,` to  `future:getContacts(),`